# Arrays and pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have this piece of program and there are some parts that I don't understand...

```
‪#‎include‬ <stdio.h>
void increment( int *ptr) {++*ptr; }

int main(){
int a[] = { 5, 10 }, i = 0; // We have: vector a=[5,10] | i=0

increment(a); //This is the same as increment(&a) isn't it? 
              //So we have: a=[6,10] | i=0

increment(&i); // We increment i so: a=[6,10] | i=1

increment(&a[i]); //We increment the element at the position a[1]: a=[6,11] | i=1

increment(a+i); //OMG! What does it mean? a is an array isn't it? Then how can we
                 //make "a+1"? and how is this an address?

printf("\nResult: i= %d\n", i);
printf( "a[0] = %d\n" "a[1] = %d\n", a[0], a[1]);
return 0;
```

}

The `printf`s return:

```
 i=1
 a[0]=6
 a[1]=12
```

How can this be explained?

Comment: `a` points to the first element of the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass an array to a function, the array decays to a pointer to the first element. So in the function, doing e.g. `*ptr` is dereferencing the first element in the array.

Also, because arrays decays to pointers, doing e.g. `a[i]` is equal to `*(a + i)`.

---

Unrelated side-note: Because of the commutative of addition, the expression `*(a + i)` can be written as `*(i + a)` which leads to `i[a]` actually being a valid expression.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but waht about:                       increment(a+i); ?

Comment: @GniruT It returns a *pointer* to the i:th element of the array `a`. If you see my answer, you will see I use `*(a + i)`, just remove the dereference operator and you have your expression.

Comment: Instead of "pointer", can we say that (a+1) in increment(a+1) returns the address of the i-th element of the array a?

Comment: @GniruT Different phrasing, means the same. Except that it's actually "(i + 1):th", since array indices are zero-based. :)

Answer (score 2):

Arrays and pointer arithmetic are the same in C. If you've not come across pointer arithmetic here's a tutorial on it:
[C Pointer Arithemtic](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm)

In essence:

```
a[3]
```

is the same as

```
*(a + 3)
```

Where `a` is a pointer.

Comment: then "&a[3]" is the same as "a+3" ?

Comment: This also equivalent to write "&3[a]"

Answer (score 2):

When we give the name of array in the function call, the address of the arrya's first element is passed

**ie; increment(a);  is same as increment(&a[0]);**

So while giving

```
incrementa(a+i);
```

since i and array a[] are both integers effectively that becomes

*incrementa **( base address of array a (ie; &a[0])  +  value of i )***

***i*** just acts as the offset to that array element

That it becomes the address of the second element which is &a[1]

so the 11 is modified to 12 while incrementing the value by the function